# Authenticate Native App with asp.net core Backend using Azure AD with Client Secret

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm currently developing a Kiosk terminal where I need to grant access for a UWP app to a REST API built with asp.net core using Azure AD. Since there is no user as it is a kiosk setup I created a Azure AD app registration (web app) and also created a key to use as client secret.

I manage to get a Bearer Access Token using a POST request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenant}/oauth2/token` providing the `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` and desired Resource (=AppId of my app registration).

In my `asp.net core` app I did enable JWTBearerAuthentication like this:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Authority = Configuration["ClientAuthentication:AADInstance"] + Configuration["ClientAuthentication:TenantId"],
    Audience = Configuration["ClientAuthentication:Audience"]
});
```

and I use the Authorize attribute in my API controller.

In this setup I always get a

> **401 unauthorized**

when calling this API using the Bearer token in the Authorization header.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the audience in the token matches the audience in your API configuration. (You can inspect the JWT with https://jwt.io) Also make sure your header is *Authorization: Bearer longtokenvalue...*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to jwt.io. Tried that and the audience matches the audience in my API configuration. Also Authorization header is correct.
One thing thats strange though: jwt.io says "invalid signature". Since the token is issued my Azure AD I'm wondering if this is the problem and if I have any influence on the signature from the app perspective...

Comment: To ensure that not a code issue, could you reproduce this issue using the code sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore)?

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, unfortunately this is a different use case. The sample you provided uses two app registrations, one for the API and one for the app and also uses delegated permissions and AD users.

Comment: The scenario I'm trying to achieve is: One app registration with a client secret (generated as key in the app registration) and then using the client id and secret to obtain a access token (which is the working part) and using this access token to authorize the client in the asp.net core web api (not working as stated in the original question). 
The reason for me going this way: the app will be running on public kiosk devices where no AD user is present. So my goal is to limit access to my REST API to those devices. Hope this makes sense :-) and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample is only for checking the code issue because I am not able to reproduce this issue.

Here is my trying:

1. register an app from Azure classic portal
2. acquire the token using the **client credentials flow** like below:

```
//7f39bae4-f852-41ae-8a7b-54d022cf65bd is the client_id of app
POST:https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=7f39bae4-f852-41ae-8a7b-54d022cf65bd&client_secret={clientSecret}&resource=7f39bae4-f852-41ae-8a7b-54d022cf65bd
```

3. clone the code sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore)
4. modify the `Startup` class as the code you provide

```
 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions {
            Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"]),
            Audience = "7f39bae4-f852-41ae-8a7b-54d022cf65bd"
        });
```

5. run the **ToDoListService** project
6. set the breakpoint for the `Get` method of `TodoListController`
7. send the request using Fiddler like below

```
GET:https://localhost:44321/api/TodoList
Authorization: bearer {accessToken}
```

The break point was hit well for me. Please ensure that the audience is the **client id** of your app. If you still have the issue, I suggest you follow the step above to check whether it helps.